# Will a Cell/B.E. SPU context waiting on a blocking read still be paged onto the SPU?

Tags: linux, cell, scheduler

Consider the case of a Cell/B.E. processor running a number of SPU contexts/threads, where that number exceeds the number of SPUs on the system.  Thus, the Linux scheduler will be running a given context until it gets to the end of its timeslice, and then swapping it out to run a different context.

In our system, we have some SPU contexts that are conceptually in a "wait" state -- we don't want them to be running now, but we want to reactivate them later.  Thus, we would like for the Linux scheduler not to swap them in and evict other SPU contexts that are currently running.

We've implemented this wait state by having the SPU context execute a spu_readch intrinsic function, which does a blocking read in the "Signal 1" communications channel from the PPU.  Then, when we want the SPU context to wake up, we write something to that channel.

Thus, the question: If a SPU context is waiting on a blocking read on a communications channel, will the Linux scheduler page it onto a SPU anyway, or will the scheduler recognize this and not page it in until something has written to the channel?

(Bonus points if you can point me to the place in the Linux kernel code where this is implemented!)